# Can i deploy 2 different applications on the same AWS server with Laravel-Forge?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, backend, persistent-storage, laravel-forge

I'm a Junior Web Developer since 3-4 months so don't blame me for this question plsss.. I have an AWS server on Laravel-Forge that contains already 2 sites (Laravel Application for Back-end and Vue Application for Front-end), i have a small mySql database configured for this application and all it's good for now. Now i'm working on a new Project that need a solid mySql database and server because it' a very important management application for my agency, so this database will contain a lot of row and this database must be persistent during the years. Now there is my question : Is better choice to manage a fresh Laravel-Forge Server for this application or maybe can i add these 2 sites and my new database on my existent server (that is actually running my first 2 sites (Back-end and Front-end) and database)? I don't want to have problems in the future cause i have 2 different Sites and databases running on the same server. Thank you for the answer and sorry for my newbie experience on programming :(

I tried looking online but no one explains these cases to novice developers, so I'm asking here because I think it's the best place

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.